# Is it possible to POST multiple Tooling SObjects with a single request?

Tags: sobject, tooling-api, bulkification, dml-operations, traceflag

I've seen and tested that I can create or update single records of `TraceFlag` (for example) using "/tooling/sobjects/SObjectName/".

However, years of working with Salesforce has ingrained in me that I should bulkify requests, rather then send them one at a time.

I've tried working with the "/tooling/composite", but this results in

```
{
    "compositeResponse": [
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "PROCESSING_HALTED",
                    "message": "Cannot make Data API calls with the Tooling API composite resource. Use the services/data/vXX.X/composite endpoint to make composite requests with Data API calls"
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "referenceId": "post_request_cbb8aef2-e4a6-4264-8df1-69ed4779ca8c"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, if I try making requests through the "/composite/sobjects" endpoint I get:

```
[
    {
        "success": false,
        "errors": [
            {
                "statusCode": "INVALID_TYPE",
                "message": "sObject type 'TraceFlag' is not supported.",
                "fields": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Or if I try sending to "/tooling/composite/sobjects",

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
]
```

Is there a way I can bulkify requests to create or update TraceFlags?
(Am I correct to believe these still fall under general API limits?)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that an answer, so much a confirmation that others have not been successful....  I guess, in a very literal sense, it is an answer without being a solution.  :-/

Comment: I'd call it an answer to your question - as in, it's not possible. Public facing documentation is confusing around this - but tooling objects don't support composite data updates and if that object isn't supported in the REST API composite sobject endpoint, you're left with no option as you've done.